# shell script variable scope after cd

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sh

Why after call **cd** command on below script, the second echo line don't work?

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE='my.log'
echo 'log line 1' >> $LOGFILE
cd folder-x
echo 'log line 2' >> $LOGFILE
```

And without cd command it's work?

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE='my.log'
echo 'log line 1' >> $LOGFILE
#cd folder-x
echo 'log line 2' >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: It will write in 2 files: `./my.log` and `./folder-x/my.log`

Comment: I'd expect that it's still working - it's just writing to `folder-x/my.log` the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create two log files. One from where you are running script. Another in folder-x.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

`LOGFILE` isn't a file variable, it's just a file *name*. Not even that, it's just text.

So what happens is:

```
echo 'log line 1' >> $LOGFILE
```

writes in to `my.log` in the current directory, because this translates to:

```
echo 'log line 1' >> my.log
```

then we

```
cd folder-x
```

and

```
echo 'log line 2' >> $LOGFILE
```

expands to:

```
echo 'log line 2' >> my.log
```

which is just what happens - in the *new* current directory.

You *could* include the current directory in `LOGFILE`, so future log statements are appended there, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE="`pwd`/my.log"
echo 'log line 1' >> $LOGFILE
cd folder-x
echo 'log line 2' >> $LOGFILE
```